# Why is NPS Api returning 503 when I try to get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I'm attempting to get park information from the National Park Service's API but res.on('data') is never getting called and I'm getting an error code of 503. This API doesn't have very much documentation and I don't have very much experience working with APIs so I could be missing something small and obvious.

```
let getPark = (parkCode, cb) => {
  let url = `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks? 
             parkCode=${parkCode}&api_key=${apiKey}`;

  https.get(url, (res) => {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      cb(body);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).  *503: The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.*  Come back later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with printing out the `res.statusCode`, which is giving you a `503`, you can print out `res.statusMessage`. When I do this I get `statusMessage: 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'`

I get the same thing when I just try to `curl` the example url they gave me. So I don't think it's your code. Every couple times it send me an html page. Maybe not ready for primetime?

Answer (score 0):

Any 5xx error means the server application is failing for some reason. Check out the status codes definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors

In your case, I think you should look at your url variable. The way you're using template literals is causing extra white space and a new line to be stored in the variable. This might be causing the api server to fail.

Try this instead:

```
let url = `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?` +
  `parkCode=${parkCode}&api_key=${apiKey}`;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that solved the 503. I'm getting a 200 now. However the response body I'm getting is html (the nps home website?). Any idea why this is? I was expecting json.

Comment: @ZachCoursey Server is probably still coming back up from it's maintenance and may be redirecting to the home page.  Try again in a few minutes